# Calculate the direction of the line through a point with a fixed distance from a point on a fixed plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to calculate the direction vector of the line through point `A` with distance `r` from point `C`. I'd like to do this with vector algebra.

This is what I had already but it is quite farfetched and I want to program it later so I'd like a cleaner solution if there is one.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frxjQ.png)

explanation image:

$b$ is the vector $b = B-C$

$c$ is the vector $c = A-B$

$b \perp c$

$a$ is the vector $a = A-C$

$E$ is a point on line $AC$

$e$ is the vector $e = E-C$

$d$ is the vector $d = B-E$

$d \perp e$

$f$ is the vector $f = A-E$

$n$ is the normal of the plane through $A$, $B$, $C$ and $E$

What do I now:
the normal $n$ (could be normalized),
the point $C$,
the point $A$,
the length of vector $b$

What do I want to know:
vector $c$

$$
||b||² = ||e|| * ||a||
$$
$$
||e|| = \frac{||b||²}{||a||}
$$
$$
||f|| = ||a|| - ||e||
$$
$$
||d|| = \sqrt{||e|| * ||f||}
$$
$$
d = \frac{||d||}{||n \times a||}(n \times a) 
$$
$$
c = f - d
$$

The second solution would just be

$$
c = f + d
$$

Comment: It sounds like this point $B$ could be any point on the circle of radius $r$ centered at $C$ in the plane specified by the normal vector. If that's true, then you won't have a unique solution. Do you have more information that would restrict it to a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

If we’re working in 2D, then let $S$ be the circle with center $C$ and radius $r$. Then the line you want passes through $A$ and is tangent to $S$. There are two such lines. Which one do you want?

If we’re working in 3D, then let $S$ be the sphere with center $C$ and radius $r$. Then again the line you want passes through $A$ and is tangent to $S$. There are an infinite number of these lines. They all lie on a cone with vertex $A$ tangent to $S$. Which one do you want?

You don’t mention it in the question text, but your title says “in a plane”, so let’s assume the 2D case.

We just need to find the direction vector $U$ of the desired line. Let $D =C-A$, $d = \|D\|$, and let $\theta$ be the angle between $D$ and $U$. Then it’s clear that $\sin\theta = r/d$ and $\cos\theta =\sqrt{d^2-r^2}/d$. Now that we know $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, we can construct the matrix that rotates through the angle $\theta$. To get the two possible $U$ vectors, just rotate the vector $D$ through the angle $\theta$ clockwise and anti-clockwise. I’m assuming you already have code to do 2D rotations. If not, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).